# Excel VBA Copy sheet to new workbook with rename sheet based cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy one sheet "RESULTADOS" to new workbook with sheet name based cell value range "U3". My code copies the sheet fine but it is giving error about name and the new file not open fine so i dont know where its mistake. I hope some help.

My code:

```
Sub CopySheetToNewWorkbook()

Dim wFrom As Workbook
Dim wTo   As Workbook

Set wFrom = ActiveWorkbook
Set wTo = Workbooks("FileResult.xlsx")

With Application
  .ScreenUpdating = False
  .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

With wFrom
  .Sheets("RESULTADOS").Range("A1:Y100").Copy
End With

With wTo
  With .Sheets("HOJA1")
       .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
       .name = wFrom.Sheets("RESULTADOS").Range("U3").Value
  End With
End With

With Application
  .ScreenUpdating = True
  .DisplayAlerts = True
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

The object graph on sheet "RESULTADOS" not copy in new workbook. What parameter is to copy the bar graph objects?

UPDATE code:

```
Sub CopySheetToNewWorkbook()

Dim wbFrom As Workbook
Dim wbTo   As Workbook
Set wbFrom = ThisWorkbook
Set wbTo = "D:\FileResult.xlsx"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With wbTo
    With .Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
       wbFrom.Sheets("RESULTADOS").Range("A1:Y100").Copy
       .Range("A1").PasteSpecial
       .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
       .Name = wbFrom.Sheets("RESULTADOS").Range("U3").Value
    End With
    .Worksheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    .Save
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you have the code? In the workbook containing the worksheet `RESULTADOS` or in another workbook?

Comment: In Worksheet Resultados have the code.

Comment: Is the idea to rename the modified worksheet `HOJA1` and then create a new worksheet `HOJA1`?

Comment: In the new book by default is "Hoja1" is there you must change the name according to the value of the cell (Range U3), maybe must delete "Worksheets.Add().name = Sheets("HOJA1")"

Comment: Is Workbook("FileResult") opened or closed?

Comment: Opened file Fileresult

Comment: I think the error is at `Worksheets.Add().name = Sheets("HOJA1")`, for `.name` is a string while `Sheets.(..)` is an object. And I think you wanted to write `.Work...`. And `Worksheets.Add().name` fails sometime for me, so I prefer splitting this operation to 2 cmmands: `Worksheets.Add()` that will implicitly activate the recently added sheet and then name it with `Activesheet.name = <some string>`

Comment: You wrote `Worksheets.Add...`: Do you want to add the worksheet `HOJA1` to `FileResult.xlsx` or to a new (3rd) workbook?

Comment: If your workbook is already opened you need to use `Set wTo = Workbooks("FileResult.xlsx")`

Comment: @VBasic2008 only copy sheet "Resultados" a new workbook and paste sheet with rename sheet based cell value U3

Comment: Why are you pasting the range to `Worksheets("HOJA1") and then renaming it to the value from `Sheets("RESULTADOS").Range("U3")`?

Comment: @GMalc The new workbook there are many sheets with ID per sheet, so I wanted to put the name of the sheet as ID from Sheets("RESULTADOS").Range("U3")

Comment: That is not the point; you save to "HOJA1" then rename it, and add a new sheet with the name "HOJAI". All you need to do is add a new sheet with the name from "U3".

Comment: @GMalc So, what should I do then and the second the pasted format must be the same, I understand the xlPasteAll is out of square.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy From One Workbook to Another

[PasteType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheetToNewWorkbook()

    Dim wbFrom As Workbook
    Dim wbTo   As Workbook
    Set wbFrom = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbTo = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\FileResult.xlsx")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With wbTo
        With .Sheets("HOJA1")
           wbFrom.Sheets("RESULTADOS").Range("A1:Y100").Copy
           .Range("A1").PasteSpecial
           .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
           .Name = wbFrom.Sheets("RESULTADOS").Range("U3").Value
        End With
        .Worksheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "HOJA1"
        '.Save
        '.Close
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, there are tow thing, it is not possible to add more sheets each time I copy from Sheets("RESULTADOS").Range("U3").Value and secondly the copy format must be full copy and not values. I prefer the fileResult is opened.

Comment: @Kais: I've edited the code. I do not understand your first question? You cannot have worksheets with the same name, so you have to explain how you will name them. If `FileResult.xlsx` is open or closed, the code will work. If you don't like it, just remove `.Open(...)`.

Comment: Thanks again, the question refers to the copy of the sheet must be the same framed format because in the new sheet the format is deconfigured over the entire width of the columns.

Comment: Because without Range ("A1:Y100"), wbFrom.Sheets ("RESULTS").copy it's generates new book ??